# How to write mongodb shell query into golang

Tags: regex, mongodb, go

I have a mongodb query that I written for shell which is working fine but now I want to transfer it into golang below is the query and solution that I tried

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"course" : /^ba$/i, "status":{"$ne":0}}).count()
```

That I tried:-

```
query := bson.M{"status": bson.M{"$ne": 0}, "course": "/^" + parameter + "$/i"}
query := bson.M{"status": bson.M{"$ne": 0}, "course": `/^` + parameter + `$/i`}
```

but not working fine can anyone please find mistake that I'm doing.

Comment: [example with regex in official repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/0af4510661f2ca5975c0237232b6bf6d3657d802/examples/documentation_examples/examples.go#L293-L310)

Comment: @NobbyNobbs how I mention the value that I need to search in this `bson.D{{"item", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^p", Options: ""}}`

Comment: I suppose smth like `bson.D{{"course", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^" + parameter + "$", Options: "i"}}`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could count documents and use regular expressions with golang mongodb driver.

```golang
pattern := "test"
count, err := coll.CountDocuments(ctx, bson.D{
    {"course", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^" + pattern + "$", Options: "i"}},
    {"status", bson.D{{"$ne", 0}}},
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(count)
```

Comment: this will result null

Comment: @PuneetJindal This could return zero but not null. It's working example.